# “Feed” icon’s action

Tags: bug, ios-app

When the sidebar is expanded, the zigzag icon is labeled “feed.”  So intuitively, it should always take us back to the feed screen.  But most of the time, it functions as a duplicate of the “back,” I.e., the previous screen viewed.  In fact, the only time it doesn’t is when the back “<“ is not visible.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,2)
- OS Version: Version 11.2 (Build 15C114)